# Combining 2 sentences into a single one

Tags: sentence-construction

I have following information

> Pete develops new software in C# and C++. He also modifies existing software written in these languages.

How do I express it in a single sentence? All my attempts look bad: I either repeat **and** many times or **software**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. For example, the following is grammatically correct:

> Pete develops new software in C# and C++ and modifies existing software written in these languages.

However, as you said, this seems repetitious. The way I, personally, would combine the above sentences is with the *both ... and* correlative conjunction:

> Pete both develops new and modifies existing software written in C# and C++.

Here is [further reading](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/conj-paired.html) on this construct.

Comment: The first one seems better

Comment: I think the second example would be sound better like this: 

"Pete both develops new software and modifies existing software written in C# and C++."

I know the meaning is clear in your example, it just sounds a bit strange. I think it's because of the "<verb> <adjective> and <verb> <adjective>" construct. "<verb> and <verb>" would sound better e.g. "Pete both develops and modifies software ..."

Comment: @SteveIves I agree, the separation of the adjective from its noun (new/existing to software) does make it sound strange, a result of trading "smoothness" for concision.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I don't know if there's a rule for this - my knowledge of the formal English grammar rules is very poor (I couldn't tell you the difference between perfect and imperfect tense), but I tend to have a knack for writing good-sounding English (perhaps as I read a lot).

Answer (score 1):

Pete creates and modifies software in C# and C++.

I replaced "develops" with "creates", because development can mean both creation and modification.

Comment: May I suggest "develops" rather than creates, since that is the term employed in the question?

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence is ambiguous as it implies modifying existing software is something extra or odd for a developer, while development itself means writing and modifying software.

Then you'd better say:

> Pete develops and modifies software in C# and C++.

Comment: This doesn't sound good. 'Meanwhile' is usually used to indicate that something else is being done elsewhere: "Pete had gone to bed early. Meanwhile, Sarah had gone out for dinner.'

Comment: Colin's answer if good. If you want to emphases that he does both at the same time, you could say "Pete develops new software in C# and C++. whilst modifying existing software in these languages.". but this doesn't really work for software development, as you would be writing a new program OR modifying an existing one, but not at exactly the same time, which is what 'whilst' implies: Compare "Coco the Clown juggled whilst trampolining" to "Coco the Clown juggled and did magic tricks".

Comment: 'yet' doesn't really work in that context, as it is used to indicate that a second action is actually contradictory to a first action. E.g. "Mary dislikes blood yet is the first-aid person in the office.". "Simon hates maths yet likes doing sudoku puzzles" or "Pete develops new software in C# and C++, yet dislikes modifying existing software written in these languages."

Comment: It can mean 'in addition' or 'and', but only when the the thing you are adding is surprising given the first thing. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/yet definition B1. So in my example, I use yet because if someone writes software, you might expect them enjoy modifying it, but he doesn't.

Comment: Can you stop editing your answer please - it bears almost no resemblance to your original answer and the comments no longer make sense.

Comment: @SteveIves I either should delete it or modify it, we can both delete all the comments, if you agree! Thank you for the help, I got what you mean